# MEAN stack auth with passport: login not working (but I can create new user)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, mean-stack

So I am trying to add local authentication to my MEAN stack app.
Everything was running smoothly. Sign up works great. But I cannot log in as a user.

I am getting:
POST /login 302 3.979 ms - 58
on the console (via Morgan)
But there is certainly an error (express routes to the "failureRedirect" set via passport)

Could it be a problem reading from the db? Why would I be able to write to it then...

A test with chai reveals that the program cannot "find user by email" from the db via User Model

anyone have any clue why this is happening?

Here is my passport strategy code:

```
/config/passport.js
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User            = require('../models/users');


module.exports = function(passport) {


// passport session setup ==================================================

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});


passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});


// local login =============================================================




passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({

    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true 
},
function(req, email, password, done) { 

    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {

        if (err)
            return done(err);

        if (!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); 


        if (!user.validPassword(password))
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); 

        return done(null, user);
    });

}));




// local sign up =============================================================


passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({

    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true 
},
function(req, email, password, done) {

    User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {

        if (err)
            return done(err);


        if (user) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
        } else {


            var newUser            = new User();


            newUser.local.email    = email;
            newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password); // use the generateHash function in our user model

            newUser.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                return done(null, newUser);
            });
        }

    });

}));

};
```

Here's the routes:

```
// /login ======================================================================

app.route('/login')
.get(function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.render('login.html');
})
 .post(passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', 
        failureRedirect : '/'

    })); 


// /signup ======================================================================

app.route('/signup')
.get(function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.render('signup.html');
})
.post(passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/profile', 
        failureRedirect : '/'
       }));
```

Comment: show your login form , does it contain email and pasword?

Comment: I'd suggest some console logging to see exactly what is being passed-over to the find call. Also, are you comparing "like with like"? Case sensitivity can be an issue for example: are you searching for an email address all in lower-case (which is similarly stored in lower-case)?

Comment: figured it out... my form didn't have name attrs

Answer (score 0):

```
Login Strategy


     // passport/login.js
        passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback : true
          },
          function(req, username, password, done) { 
            // check in mongo if a user with username exists or not
            User.findOne({ 'username' :  username }, 
              function(err, user) {
                // In case of any error, return using the done method
                if (err)
                  return done(err);
                // Username does not exist, log error & redirect back
                if (!user){
                  console.log('User Not Found with username '+username);
                  return done(null, false, 
                        req.flash('message', 'User Not found.'));                 
                }
                // User exists but wrong password, log the error 
                if (!isValidPassword(user, password)){
                  console.log('Invalid Password');
                  return done(null, false, 
                      req.flash('message', 'Invalid Password'));
                }
                // User and password both match, return user from 
                // done method which will be treated like success
                return done(null, user);
              }
            );
        }));
```

We now define our routes for the application in the following module which takes the instance of Passport created in app.js above. Save this module in

```
    module.exports = function(passport){

      /* GET login page. */
      router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        // Display the Login page with any flash message, if any
        res.render('index', { message: req.flash('message') });
      });

      /* Handle Login POST */
      router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('login', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash : true 
      }));

      /* GET Registration Page */
      router.get('/signup', function(req, res){
        res.render('register',{message: req.flash('message')});
      });

      /* Handle Registration POST */
      router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('signup', {
        successRedirect: '/home',
        failureRedirect: '/signup',
        failureFlash : true 
      }));

      return router;
    }
```